# How to communicate with php file on Firebase storage?

Tags: php, android, database, firebase, storage

so I have been using my old website from `www.000webhost.com` and I had few php files that I was communicating with them from my android app and they were sending me back some data (pictures and objects decoded to strings using `echo`)

on the android side I was writing the url as `<root_url>/somefile.php`

I added some `POST` messages to input few data (like who am I and what data do I want to get back), and using some complicated functions as this:

```
public String performPostCall(String requestURL, HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

        URL url;
        String response = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(requestURL);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);


            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response+=line;
                }
            }
            else {
                response="";

            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException me){
            me.printStackTrace();
            String message = me.getMessage();
            message += "!";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return response;
    }
```

I was able to retrieve the data (I shrinked the code down because its very long, if this is unclear I'll upload the rest of it)..

Now I'm trying to upgrade my server to the Firebase server and I managed to read/write data on the **Database** using the `addValueEventListener` methods.

But I also want to be able to access the storage, to communicate with my php codes..

Basically I need to download some pictures at beginning.

I know I can use the same `AddChildEventListener` method and read the pictures as decoded strings from my database but these pictures are uploaded manually by users so I think that **Storage** will be an easier way for both sides..

But I just can't get the process for how to set it right, I couldn't find any tutorial or guide for that..

Is this even possible? if it is, can it work on the same principle with the same methods (the same function I used for my old website)

Any tutorial / guide / explanations would be much appreciated !